# How to find the TLS version for the HTTPS Request library?

Tags: node.js

I am running on Node v10.16.0 and I have a client and server both using HTTPS. I am trying to measure the performance of my network, in particular the https.request(GET) my client makes to the server. I have a question that I can't seem able to answer:
What version of TLS does Node v10.16.0 http.request run?

The getProtocol() is able to be called on a tls socket from tls.createServer(). I am trying to find the version of tls on a socket from https.createServer()

Comment: you should rollback your edit then ask another question else the answer(s) below make no sense (or don't as it off-topic on SO to ask for tutorials)

Answer (score 2):

`https.request()` uses the [TLS support built into node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback).  When the socket is active, it appears you can call `socket.getCipher()` and get a result such as:

```
{ name: 'AES256-SHA', version: 'TLSv1.2' }
```

So, presumably, you could call that function from one of the events that occurs during a request and use [res.socket](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_socket) to get the live socket being used in the request and then use that socket to call `socket.getCipher()`.

Here's an example:

```
const https = require('https');

const req = https.request("https://www.google.com", function(res) {

    console.log(res.socket.getCipher());

    res.on('data', function(data) {
        // something here on incoming data
    });
});
req.end();
```

I have node v12.13 installed and this outputs:

```
 { name: 'TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384', version: 'TLSv1.3' }
```

for me.  You can run it on your own node version to see what you have.

Comment: @AndrewJones - Did this answer your question?